# Why does the timer stop? and how can I prevent it (Javascript) - Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, timer, countdown

Ok , I have a page on my website, where the client has to view advertisement (website) for 20 seconds. I display this website that he has to view in an iframe tag. and above I have a 20 sec countdown timer.

I also made sure that when window loses focus , the timer stops. to make sure that the client in actually viewing the website.

But I have a problem. When the client clicks something on the website within the Iframe, the counter actually stops (meaning it lost focus). But I don't want that to happen, I want the timer to stop counting down , only if he goes to another tap or another window. But I want it to keep counting if he clicks links in the website within the Iframe.

here's the code I use:

```
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myInterval;
var seconds=20;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).focus(function () {
        clearInterval(myInterval); // Clearing interval if for some reason it has not been cleared yet
           if (!flag)
           { myInterval = setInterval(tick, 1000);}
    }).blur(function () {
        clearInterval(myInterval); // Clearing interval on window blur
    });
myInterval = setInterval(tick, 1000);
});
function tick()
{
      display();

        if (seconds>0)
        {
         seconds--;
        }
        else
        {
          document.getElementById('TrafficHeader').innerHTML +="<?php include_once('Code.php'); 
          ?>";
          clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
}
function display()
{
   $("#TrafficHeader").html(seconds);
}
</script>
<div id="TrafficHeader" style="height:100px; background-color:grey; padding:20px;"></div>
<iframe src="http://www.website.com" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</html>
```

Any help will be really appreciated
thanks in advance

Comment: `document.getElementById('TrafficHeader').innerHTML +="<?php include_once('Code.php'); ?>";` What is this? Are you trying to inject a PHP code into an already compiled webpage?

Comment: @MiroMarkarian as long as that `Code.php` does not have line breaks, that is a valid code

Comment: actually yes, that's what am trying to do Miro, cuz I need this php code to be triggered only when seconds<=0 , so I had to inject the php code into the javascript. and it's working perfectly, that's not the issue :) , but if you think that's not good thing to do, would like to hear why :)

Comment: Did a lot of googling and couldn't find answer... -.-

Comment: @Shady: The PHP code is executed once the page is served, not when the JS is executed

Comment: as @Bergi says, The php inclusion won't work -- once the page is sent to the browser, that's the end of PHP's involvement in the process. The way to do what you're trying to achieve is with Ajax -- make an ajax request to the file you want to include, and then use JS to add the response from that request into the page. But note that as far as PHP is concerned, it will be a new page load, so if you were relying on variables being kept, they won't be. This Ajax method is quite a common technique; there are lots of tutorials on the web to help you.

Comment: The PHP inclusion will work so long as there's no characters that would break the javascript, such as a `"`.  It would end up as an ugly, fragile string literal.  Ajax would likely be suboptimal in this case since it adds an additional client request for something that likely doesn't need one (and which in this case seems like it would introduce far more transfer/latency).  A better solution unless Ajax is actually warranted would be to output the content in a hidden div and then pull the content in from there/clone or move the hidden element.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [focusin](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/) and [focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) instead of just focus and blur.  And adjust your logic accordingly to accomodate the multiple `focusin` fires..  Something like

```
$(window).focusout(function() {
  window.isStillActive = false;
  ...
}
$(window).focusin(function() {
  if (!window.isStillActive) {
    ...
    clearTimeout();
    ...
    window.isStillActive = true;
  }
}
```